# Как прервать действие

Tags: jquery

Есть две функции

```
var widget = $('popup');
function show() { widget.show(); };
function hide() { widget.show().delay(delay).fadeOut(); };
```

Проблема в том, что если вызывается `show()` раньше чем закончит выполняться `hide()`, то показываемый элемент всё равно скроется.

Можно ли как-нибудь при вызове `show()` прерывать предыдущие действия для `widget`

Comment: метод `.stop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lexxl, немного откорректировав комментарий, я добился желаемого. Сам использовал `stop()`, но без аргументов он работал не так.

```js
var widget = $('#popup').hide();

$('#show').click(function(e) {
  widget.stop(true).show(); 
});

$('#hide').click(function(e) {
  widget.show().delay(7000).fadeOut(); 
});
```

```css
#popup {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popup">Контент внутри</div>

<input type="button" id="show" value=Показать>
<input type="button" id="hide" value="Скрыть">
```